# SmartyPDT doesn't work with PDT

Tags: eclipse, smarty, eclipse-pdt

I have Eclipse 3.7.2 with PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature 3.0.0.v201201110400-77-184_2BEICRgM_fMVcz0M4Va9O. According to installation instruction of SmartyPDT http://code.google.com/p/smartypdt/wiki/InstallSmartyPDT I try to install it, but when I add local archieve .zip as repository, I have message:

> there are no categorized items

What is here a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it. I unchecked "Group items by category". It was in instruction, I didn't see it before.